# What's the correct answer about getservbyname?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I don't know what's the correct answer about getservbyname.

Sentence `sp = getservbyname("example", "tcp")`

a. is used by the client to obtain the service's port.

b. can only be used if we have permission to modify /etc/services file.

c. will be used by the server to obtain the service's port, if we have access to /etc/services.

d. a y b are correct.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you trying to test us? How about [reading the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyname)?

Comment: I've already read it. I have an exam about this and I can't find the answer.

Comment: We normally decline to help people with their homework or with studying for exams.   I wrote an answer in this case because the exam question itself needs debunking: all four possibilities are wrong.

Comment: (You can ask questions about your coursework as long as they are good questions in themselves - see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)'s advice on how to write a good question for this site - and as long as it doesn't seem like you're asking us to do all the work for you.  If you get someone else to do all the work for you, you won't learn anything.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the possibilities are wrong to first order.  This is a bad exam question and you may tell your instructor I said so.

(a) is the least wrong answer.  [`getservbyname`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyname) *could* be used by a generic TCP client to determine what port of a server to connect to, given a textual service name.  However, it has several other uses, and it's also obsolete: new programs should be using [`getaddrinfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) (which does both `getservbyname`'s job and `gethostbyname`'s job, simultaneously, and more flexibly).

(b) is completely wrong. `getservbyname` *may* require *read* access to `/etc/services`, depending on how [Name Service Switch](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf) is configured; under no circumstances will it require *write* access to that file.  (The contents of `/etc/services` are defined by the [IANA service name and port number registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), and nowadays the only programs that should ever modify that file are the sysadmin's text editor and the OS's package manager.  I don't remember off the top of my head whether there was ever a C library interface to update that file, but if it exists it would be even more obsolete than `getservbyname`.)

(c) is partially wrong; a server *could* reasonably use `getservbyname` to look up the port that it was supposed to bind to, but, as explained above, it would at most need *read* access to `/etc/services` to do that.  (Saying "permission to modify" in option (b) and then just "access" in (c) is sloppy question-writing technique.)

(d) is wrong since (b) is wrong.

Comment: I checked the `getservbyname(3)` man page on Fedora 27. The man page does not appear to mention the function is obsolete or deprecated. In fact, the docs says the function is Posix conforming so it will likely be around a long time. Here is a similar man page, but it has some omissions. For example, the linked man page does not list Posix.1-2008: [`getservbyname(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyname).

Comment: @jww: The most reliable and up to date man pages are at the [Linux man-pages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/), which does list POSIX.1-2008 for [getservbyname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getservbyname.3.html). While `getservbyname()` is not obsoleted by POSIX.1 because so much existing code is still using it, [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)/[`getnameinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html) is the proper, recommended interface in POSIX.1 for internet address and service resolution.

Comment: That said, the wording on e.g. [`services(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html) is poor.. it really should suggest using `getaddrinfo()` instead. Might be worth [sending a RFC patch/suggestion](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/reporting_bugs.html).

Comment: @jww Indeed, as Nominal Animal says, the function has not been _formally_ obsoleted/deprecated by POSIX (if it had been, I would have said so) but informally speaking, when new programs should use something else, I think "obsolete" is a fair thing to say.